# Undefined local variable or method, yet variable is defined in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, routes

I am getting the error `undefined local variable or method 'exercise' for #<#<Class:0x007fb8b1638be0>:0x007fb8b1627318>`

The error is being called on a partial rendered on my `workouts#show` page.  The error is on this line:

```
<%= form_for(exercise, method: "post") do |f| %>
```

And here is the context on the `workouts#show` page:

```
<% if @workout.exercises.count == 0 %>
        <p>Looks like you get a freebie for this one!  No score report today.  Rest up and drink some water.  It ain't always that easy...</p>
      <% else %>
        <% @workout.exercises.each do %>
          <p><%= exercise.name %></p>
          <%= render 'reports/form', report: Report.new, exercise: @exercise %>
          <% if current_user.admin? %>
            <%= link_to "Delete", [exercise.workout, exercise], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <h4>Your Previous Results<h4>
          <% @workout.exercises.each do %>
            <h5><%= exercise.name %></h5>
            <%= render @workout.exercise.results %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <% if current_user.admin? %>
        <%= render 'exercises/form' %>
      <% end %>
```

Usually, I know this means the variable is not defined in the controller, but the variable is defined.  Here's the `workouts#controller`:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    workout = @workout
    exercise = workout.exercises.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :user_id)
  end
end
```

And the `exercises_controller`:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:destroy, :create]

  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.new(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:post_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercise.find(params[:id])

    if comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
    params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :seconds, :weight, :reps)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

I have also been having trouble with routing (these are nested routes), so that may or may not be a factor:

`routes.rb` is:

```
resources :workouts do
    resources :exercises do
      resources :reports, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

And my routes themselves are:

```
workout_exercise_reports POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports(.:format)     reports#create
 workout_exercise_report DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports/:id(.:format) reports#destroy
       workout_exercises GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#index
                         POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#create
    new_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/new(.:format)                      exercises#new
   edit_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id/edit(.:format)                 exercises#edit
        workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#destroy
                workouts GET    /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#index
                         POST   /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#create
             new_workout GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                                            workouts#new
            edit_workout GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)                                       workouts#edit
                 workout GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#destroy
```

I would love any help or wisdom anyone can share on anything I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `@exercise` variable in your controller.
Add this in your workout controller:

```
def show
  @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
  @exercise = Exercise.new  
end
```

And this in your view:

```
<%= form_for([@workout, @exercise]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The `[@workout, @exercise]` is necessary since you're using a nested form.

Comment: This works for the variables.  However, this routing renders the error `No route matches [POST] "/workouts/workout_exercise_path"`.

Comment: It still says `No route matches [POST] "/workouts/workout_exercise_path"`.

Comment: Ok,@Liz  I've edited my post again regarding the part in your controller

Comment: I added the `new` method you suggested in the exercise controller (and changed `comment` to `exercise`, as I assume that's what you meant.  Unfortunately it still didn't change the error.

Comment: You missed a plural exerciceS somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112620/discussion-between-graham-slick-and-liz).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@exercise = workout.exercises.new
<%= form_for(@exercise,:url=>"/workouts/#{@workout.id}/exercises", method: "post") do |f| %>
```

As you declar it as a local variable it is not accessable out side that just declar it as a instance variable

Comment: This at least changed the error to `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`, called on the same line.

Comment: add the form part too

Comment: It seems to be progressing!  Now the error reads `undefined method 'exercises_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb8b9a493d0>:0x007fb8b9a281a8>`.

Comment: add the path where you need to submit that form

Comment: i added the path check it out

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with this.  For some reason that route generates the error `No route matches [POST] "/workouts/workout_exercise_path"`.

Comment: i added the routes itself in the answer check it out

Comment: That's unfortunately with the route you suggested.

Comment: sry just remove the `new` from url

Comment: Still getting `No route matches [POST] "/workouts/workout_exercise_path"`

Comment: post what you written in the form `url`  let me see what the worng on that

Comment: I copied your `<%= form_for(@exercise,:url=>"/workouts/#{@workout.id}/exercises", method: "post") do |f| %>`
exactly.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: ok try  this `<%= form_for(@exercise,{:url=>"/workouts/#{@workout.id}/exercises", :method=> "post"}) do |f| %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112621/discussion-between-pitabas-prathal-and-liz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the variable as an instance variable ( with an `@` prefix ) in your controller if you need to get access in your view. The exercise variable that you instantiate is just a local and has scope only inside your action. That's the reason why you get an undefined error in your partial.

Edit : also, to get rid of your path error, add `url: workout_exercises_path` to your form_for becasue you use nested resources for your workout-exercises combo